# How to enable zooming in a Microsoft Chart with intervals of seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart

I'm using a Microsoft Chart to graph some data with the X axis as `DateTime`, but when I try zooming in the chart with intervals of seconds the chart doesn't respond.

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Enable range selection and zooming end user interface
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss";

        chart1.Series.Add("Series2");

        var serie = chart1.Series["Series1"];
        serie.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;


        // Populate series with random data
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), random.Next(45, 95));
            chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), random.Next(5, 75));
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        // Set series chart type
        chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;

        // Set point labels
        chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        chart1.Series["Series2"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

        // Enable X axis margin
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;

    }
```

If I change this

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), random.Next(45, 95));
```

for this

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate()+pointIndex, random.Next(45, 95));
```

The chart allows to perform zoom on the series but the label in the X axis is shown always as "12:00:00"

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are passing your datetime as a double.  Make sure you are using the correct `AddXY` for Datetime.  My guess is it's defaulting it to the type double so the chart just thinks you are passing two double points and not a datetime.  Maybe remove the `ToOADate` and just pass it `DateTime.Now`.

See [Microsoft Doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.addxy?view=netframework-4.8)

Under Remarks it says:

> In order for DateTime formatting to have an effect, a value must be a DateTime object.

If the issue is you want to add time to your datetime then do something like

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(pointIndex), random.Next(45, 95));
```